# Overriding title attribute with ui.bootstrap.tooltip directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a directive definition so that when there is an element with a title attribute, it is replaced with a tooltip directive ([from ui.bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip)). Here is my directive so far:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.components.directives.title', [
  'ui.bootstrap.tooltip'
])
.directive('title', function($compile) {

  return {
    priority: 1,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      tElement.attr('tooltip', tElement.attr('title'));
      tElement.removeAttr('title');;
    }
  };

});
```

And here are my tests:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: title', function () {

  var element, scope, rootScope, compile;

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('app.components.directives.title'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    // Cache these for reuse    
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    compile = $compile;

    // Set up the outer scope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.message = 'hello';

    // Define and compile the element
    element = angular.element('<div title="Tooltip message: {{ message }}"></div>');
    element = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should replace the title attribute with a tooltip attribute', function() {
    expect(element.attr('tooltip')).toEqual('Tooltip message: {{ message }}');
  });

  it('should get rid of the title attribute', function() {
    expect(element.attr('title')).toBeFalsy();
  });

});
```

The first test passes, but when I use this in my actual application, the tooltip directive never gets registered. The second test fails because the title somehow sticks around. I have a hunch it has to do with the fact that I am {{binding}} inside the title value, but I'm not quite sure how to fix.

TLDR: tooltip doesn't compile, title sticks around.